# How to make chamfered shapes in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shapes

Like a triangle = an hexagon that has three sides with one size and another three with another one. NOT chamfered appearance. Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain how it isn't a chamfered appearance as it's hard to understand your question?

Comment: You have to draw it manually in Photoshop. Do you have Illustrator. Its got better tools for such a task.

Comment: So what you want is a regular polygon? That's what an hexagon is. There's a polygon tool in Photoshop, have you tried that?

Answer (score -1):

This kind of corner editing power doesn't exist in Adobe Photoshop, and has only been in Illustrator for a few of the more recent versions. They (Adobe and its users) don't have experience with, nor understand how CAD, 3D and other 2D drawing apps have offered this, forever.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50366/discussion-on-answer-by-confused-how-to-make-chamfered-shapes-in-photoshop).